# Vscode Localhost:3000 Showing White Screen - React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, nav

UPDATE: Source code is added. Problem seems to be with the additional page component I made. Problems are with the code in Home, Product Description, Tweets, and ColdEmails. I do not know how to add source code added.

This is how the code in the page "Home" looks like:

import React from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react'

class Home extends Component {
render() {
return (

## This is the Home Page

)
}
}
export default Home

The issue seems to be in the import of Home - Cold emails and or between the function from Home to cold emails. As once I remove everything except the navigation import and navigation function the nav bar that I have created is shown. Thanks in advance!

```
import './App.css';

//Import all the components at the top
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'
import Home from './components/Home'
import ProductDescription from './components/ProductDescription'
import Tweets from './components/Tweets'
import ColdEmails from './components/ColdEmails'

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <Navigation/> 
      <Home/>
      <ProductDescription/>
      <Tweets/>
      <ColdEmails/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I'm trying to display the nav bar ui and pages after including additional imports of the other pages.

Comment: You need to keep narrowing it down. From home to cold emails inclusive that's 4 components. Render them one by one and see which one causes the error. Then go into that component and try and see what the error is in there. Also we can't really help if you don't post the actual source code that's causing the issue

Comment: Update: The issue was related to an error in the pages. Which resolved the white screen temporarily. Another issue related to the white screen was fixed by closing and reopening Vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely its one of your imported components. Usually a white screen means TypeError. Like a value is being called that doesn't fit the type it wants to render.

For example: Calling an object, but trying to render it as a string.

Comment: Yep you're correct, it was exactly that. The imported component had improper syntax.